# Tel Number visualization pattern - space after every second number

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, data-visualization

I have an Editabe Datatable. After a user inserts the tel number into the  tel column which is an input text box, and the ok button is clicked, I need to visualize it as the following:

INPUT   390239266655

OUTPUT  +39 02 39 26 66 55

so I need to put a space after every second number, and putting + at the begining.
How can I do this ?

The following is the validation I have:

```
    <ui:define name="validation-tag">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9+]*" for="contactPhoneNumber" />
    </ui:define>
```

Comment: you can use a seperate method in your bean to convert this. `<h:outputtext value="#{bean.convertItem(item.number)}` ... the method is something like this `public String convertItem(int number)`. (The item is your current value with the number attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to write a converter, here it is the solution :

```
@FacesConverter(value = "phoneConverter")
public class PhoneConverter
    implements
    Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(
        FacesContext context,
        UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    String stringToDisplay = null;
    //
    //      if (value != null && !value.equals("") && value.startsWith("+")) {
    //          stringToDisplay = value.substring(1).trim();
    //      }
    return stringToDisplay;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(
        FacesContext context,
        UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    String stringToDisplay = (String) value;
    String resultToDisplay = null;
    try {
        //          if (!stringToDisplay.startsWith("+")) {
        if (stringToDisplay != null && !stringToDisplay.equals("")) {
                            resultToDisplay = getPhoneNumbFormat(stringToDisplay);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("PhoneConverter replaceAll failed!!! object:={} NOT FOUND!!!", stringToDisplay, e);
    }

    return resultToDisplay;

}

    private String getPhoneNumbFormat(
        String phoneNumber) {
    String resultToDisplay = null;
    if (!phoneNumber.startsWith("+")) {
        resultToDisplay = "+" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 2).concat(" ") + phoneNumber.substring(2).replaceAll("(.{2})(?!$)", "$1 ");
    } else if (!phoneNumber.substring(0, 3).startsWith(" ")) {
        resultToDisplay = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3).concat(" ") + phoneNumber.substring(3).replaceAll("(.{2})(?!$)", "$1 ");
    }
    return resultToDisplay;
}
}
```